# Using onboard video output instead of graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, dell-latitude

I have DELL latitude e6410 laptop.
Since most of the time i have no real use of the capabilities of the video card, i was wondering if i can switch the laptop screen to use the on board video output (if exists) and not the NVIDIA graphics card.

Motherboard model : dell 0k42jr

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Dell has chosen not to implement switchable graphics on the Latitude E6410 series.

I'm not able to find any information from Dell supporting that statement, but can't find the contrary either (Nvidia Optimus). Other owners of this type of notebook [write](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12126338&postcount=27) that Nvidia's discrete graphics card is the only video card being detected by the OS.

If there's no option in your BIOS for selecting the graphics card then I guess you're out of luck and you'll have to stick using your Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Too bad for me ..     Any ideas how make the GPU work on low clock/energy ?  Thanks !